# Change Conda environment via powershell script (for Gitlab-CI)

Tags: powershell, conda, gitlab-ci

I am running some automated Python tests with GitLab-CI on a Windows 10 machine. The GitLab-Runner on the machine used to work with `executor = "shell"` using the simple Windows shell. This recently stopped working (The docs say support for this shell is depreceated) and the only way to get it work again has been to use the powershell instead with adding `shell = "powershell"` to our `config.toml` file. For the tests to run, we need to activate a conda environment. Unfortunately, this seems not to work via the powershell script that GitLab-CI creates for the job.

When I open the powershell manually logged in as the user that is executing the gitlab runner jobs, changing conda environments works. I have run `conda init powershell` and can change the environment with `conda activate myenv`. Yet, when I include the following in my `gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```
script:
  - conda activate myenv
  - conda list
```

the output from `conda list` confirms that the environment `myenv` is not activated and instead the base environment is used.

Also trying the absolute path like this

```
script:
  - conda activate C:\Users\myuser\Miniconda3\envs\myenv
  - conda list
```

does not work.

So it seems like I can manually activate the correct conda environment in the powershell, but activating the environment via the powershell script created by GitLab-CI does not work. Is there a fix for this problem? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like gitlab executes each line of the script in a separate subshell. Combine the commands into a single line.

If that doesn't work, most `conda` commands will accept the name of the environment as parameter `-n`:

```
conda list -n myenv
conda install -n myenv PackageName
...
```

As long as you're just using `conda`, it shouldn't be necessary to activate the environment.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! When I run `conda activate myenv; conda list` in powershell manually, I get the expected output starting with `# packages in environment at C:\Users\myuser\Miniconda3\envs\myenv:`. Unfortunately, when I include `- conda activate myenv; conda list` in my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file `conda list` is still executed in the base environment starting its output with `# packages in environment at C:\Users\myuser\Miniconda3:`. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Strange. Unfortunately, I'm missing practical experience with both PowerShell and GitLab CI. I've updated my answer with a new suggestion that doesn't depend on either of these.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Your updated answer solves the problem perfectly. `conda list -n myenv` does give the expected output when used in the `.gitlab-ci.yml`. Also, I am able to run the unit tests in the correct environment with `conda run -n myenv python myunittests.py`.

Comment: 'conda run -n myenv python ... ' helps a lot, even on Windows Docker files in the Gitlab CI. However, here the output of the command is not displayed in the Gitlab CI job logs...?

Answer (score 0):

As it seems to be a problem within powershell but not with `cmd`, one could use the following in the gitlab-ci yaml:

```
- cmd '/C' 'conda activate myenv && python myunittests.py'
```